# CGAL Correspondence between skeleton and input surface not working

Tags: c++, cgal

I'm new to CGAL and got a problem with Skeleton.

I use CGAL-4.11 (64 bits); I successfully created Skeleton of 3D polyhedron (elephant.off file) using `CGAL::extract_mean_curvature_flow_skeleton(tmesh, skeleton);`
as it shown at https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_skeletonization/Surface_mesh_skeletonization_2simple_mcfskel_example_8cpp-example.html

All compiled and run without any errors, including the export of correspondence between vertices of the input surface and skeleton vertices with this code:

```
// Output skeleton points and the corresponding surface points  
output.open("correspondance-poly.cgal");
BOOST_FOREACH(Skeleton_vertex v, vertices(skeleton))
    BOOST_FOREACH(vertex_descriptor vd, skeleton[v].vertices)
        output << "2 " << skeleton[v].point << " " << get(CGAL::vertex_point, tmesh, vd)  << "\n";
```

But when I looked to visualization of this correspondence I found a terrible thing. Instead of a nice brush it looks like a random edges, please see 
[screenshot (look at the chaotic blue lines)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG3y7.png).

**UPD: The question is solved! Great thanks to @sloriot**
The problem was with old 'Mean_curvature_flow_skeletonization.h' file, the solution is [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/2558).

Comment: I think this was fixed by this [PR](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/2558) and the fix is part of 4.10.2. What version are you using?

Comment: I use CGAL-4.11, 64 bits

Comment: Great thanks, it works!!! (CGAL-4.11 still has the old version of Mean_curvature_flow_skeletonization.h)